# Allow users to enter fullscreen mode in UWP App made with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

So I've been facing a really strange problem, I'm making a UWP App using unity the app is set to go fullscreen when it starts and this works fine, except when I exit fullscreen mode using the button at the top:
[image]

for some reason I can't get back to fullscreen again,the full screen button turns into the maximize minimize button.
Is there a way to control which options appear there I tried to search every where but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Is the following answer on MSDN useful for you: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2041bf05-da81-443e-ae55-fbdf72e75516/uwpuwp-full-screen-button-missing?forum=wpdevelop) ?

Comment: the thing is this doesn't work with unity, or maybe I just can't get it to work with unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default style for UWP apps when they are in full screen.  It will automatically add the button (to remove it from full-screen) and remove the button (when it's not in full-screen).  Users can enter full-screen by pressing `Shift + Win + Enter` or you can put them in full-screen programmatically.

If you want a button to allow them to go to full-screen easier then you will have to write your UI to accomplish that.  Some apps overwrite the title-bar while others just give the option via context etc.

To use a custom title bar look into:

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar
```

and also

```
Window.Current.SetTitleBar
```